# Count the number of features joined by shortest_line function conditioned

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression, count, geometry-generator

Using the shortest_line function conditioned to a table attribute to return the shortest line joining features of the same layer as it shows in this expresion:

```
shortest_line(
    $geometry,
    aggregate(
        'PROP',
        'collect',
        $geometry,
        "VALUE" = '2'
    )
)
```

[image: 1]

Is there any solution to count the number of features that are joined to each point and place a dynamically label?

I have prepared the following expression using the array_length and overlay_nearest functions which does not work satisfactorily as you can see in the screenshot:

```
CASE
    WHEN "VALOR"=2 
    THEN 
    array_length(
        overlay_nearest(
            'PROP',
            $id,
            limit:=8,
            max_distance:=7
        )
    ) - 1
    ELSE NULL
END
```

[image: 2]

Comment: providing sample data would help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
count(
    $id, 
    group_by:=overlay_nearest ('PROP', $id, "VALOR" = 2)[0]
)-1
```

This returns to how many other points each point with `VALOR=2` is connected. The point itself is not counted. If you want to count it as well, simply delete `-1` at the end of the expression.

[image]